# Cannot find /home/fedora/jenkins_home - does not exist

Tags: linux, centos

I'm running a backup client (jungle disk) on a Centos7 machine & am getting errors:

```
Backup: Failed to backup single file: ve_device_add
```

Error Details (My Secure Backup Server 3.19.0.0xFileOpenFailed - Permission denied (13)
Exception Code: xFileOpenFailed (15)
Time: 2017-09-01 3:35:57 AM (GMT-5)
Detailed Message: Permission denied (13)
Error Location: /home/fedora/jenkins_home/workspace/jdclient@2/MSB3/MSBPortUnix.cpp:104 
   via /home/fedora/jenkins_home/workspace/jdclient@2/MSB3/MSBPortUnix.cpp:378 
   via /home/fedora/jenkins_home/workspace/jdclient@2/MSB3/BlockBackupManager.cpp:859 
   via /home/fedora/jenkins_home/workspace/jdclient@2/MSB3/BlockBackupManager.cpp:738

I cannot seem to find these files, there is no directory /home/fedora nor anything referencing 'jenkins' if I search the whole filesystem.

I'm assuming this must be some link hidden somewhere in the filesystem but I do not know why I cannot find it? (logged in as root)

any ideas where these phantom files could be located?

Comment: check here, `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jdclient@2` ??

Comment: no - nothing there,  what are these files related to?

Comment: `/var/lib/jenkins` is the home folder of the jenkins user. Every thing related to jenkins is there. The workspace folder is where all your projects' information is stored.

Comment: no jenkins user, no installed packages - no idea where this is coming from